# Magento: How to get range in price filter working in the latest version

Tags: magento

Latest version of Magento allows me to filter the price only on fixed slabs for example

```
price=1,1000
```

means, with in a range of 0 to 1000 and

```
price=2,1000
```

means, with in a range of 1000 to 2000 etc..,

But I am looking giving an option to the user to select the minimum and maximum price to filter the products... something like result for price btw, $200 to $3000 or $300 to $2000, how can I achieve this?

Is there a different url parameter in the new version? or someother way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably have to download an extension. They are usually free to $100 max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1.** Here is a [thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/65135/) discussed on Magento Forum on custom price filtering. Here people have shared self modified code to filter out products. Although code may be version dependent. Hopefully this will work for you..

**Solution 2.** Another solution which also worked for me :

You can configure step of price ranges via admin panel. Log in into admin panel and go to System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Layered Navigation. There select "Manual" in dropdown 'Price Navigation Step Calculation' and enter preferred values into next two input fields.